# Twilio step by step

Tags: python-3.x, twilio-api

I am starting with Twilio, and I can already send and receive WhatsApp messages from my sandbox.

What I am not understanding is how to do this for other phone numbers? Currently I can only do it for one number.

I have already modified my plan and paid $20.00 to get started, however, I cannot send messages to another number.

Which step did I skip?

Answer (score 1):

To use the WhatsApp API outside the sandbox, you need to fulfill the following requirements:

- Have an upgraded Twilio account
- Purchase a Twilio number via the console
- Have a Meta Business Manager account

Once you have these requirements, follow these steps:

1. [Create a WhatsApp Sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up#1-create-a-whatsapp-sender)
2. [Link your WhatsApp Business Account with your Twilio Account](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up#2-link-your-whatsapp-business-account-with-your-twilio-account)
3. [Verify your WhatsApp Business Number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up#3-verify-your-whatsapp-business-number)
4. [Register your number with WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up#4-register-your-number-with-whatsapp)

Here's a link to the [detailed instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up).

PS: Also check out this article that explains under which circumstances it's possible to [bring your own number to Twilio's WhatsApp API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052171393-Can-I-activate-my-own-phone-number-for-WhatsApp-on-Twilio-). But I have the feeling you'd rather want to go with the above-mentioned flow.

Comment: What would be "Have a Meta Business Manager accoun"?

Have a whatsapp number set up as Busines?

Comment: Go here to [sign up for the Meta Business Manager](https://business.facebook.com/) or use your existing one of you, for example, already buy ads on Facebook. This is not (yet) related to your WhatsApps number.

Comment: I will post my doubt as an answer because it did not fit here.